What are the optimal values to set for busy-polling?
I have an application written in C++ for reading market data. The networking layer is implemented using boost asio, effectively tcp ssl websockets. When the market throughput is high, I can observe some unusual queueing of network packets, I know there should be some delay but not that much. For asio I use all the tricks in the book:

Concurrency hint unsafe
io_context per thread
calling ioc.poll() in a busy loop

But sill seeing some delays.
Should I set /proc/sys/net/core/busy_poll and /proc/sys/net/core/busy_read as well for lower latency and scheduling? And if yes what are the optimal values, given I have no shortage of cpu power?

I'm not convinced that poll() in a busy loop is actually better than run(). Do you have a source on that?

@sehe, was advised such in #boost-beast slack channel by library maintainers.

What is the linux-kernel tag doing here? Care to elaborate?

@0andriy I'm guessing because of the kernel parameter tweaking.

@EduardRostomyan can you please clarify your question ? "invoking the poll() system call in a loop" is not the same thing as "using SO_BUSY_POLL". That is because the latter will issue system calls "at line rate" if no data is there, while the latter will make a (single) poll() syscall spin in kernel for the given amount of time. So if you do wish to "poll hot", use busy poll, not poll() in a tight code loop.
